# Fragment's onStart() and onResume() not called when using AndroidView in Composable Interoperability

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose, android-lifecycle

I'm using Compose's AndroidView to re-use my Fragment which has Google maps in it. The map view is bound to start and resume on `onStart()` and `onResume()` as usual.

```
override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        Timber.d("Chargers Fragment OnStart")
        bi.map.onStart()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Timber.d("Chargers Fragment OnResume")
        bi.map.onResume()
```

I've created a FragmentContainer Composable to re-use the fragment:

```
@Composable
fun FragmentContainer(
    containerId: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    commit: FragmentTransaction.(containerId: Int) -> Unit,
    onFragmentViewCreated: (containerId: Int) -> Unit
) {
    var initialized by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier,
        factory = { context ->
            FragmentContainerView(context)
                .apply { id = containerId }
        },
        update = { view ->
            if (initialized) {
                fragmentManager.onContainerAvailable(view)
                onFragmentViewCreated(view.id)
            } else {
                fragmentManager.commit { commit(view.id) }
                initialized = true
            }
        }
    )
}

private fun FragmentManager.onContainerAvailable(view: FragmentContainerView) {
    val method = FragmentManager::class.java.getDeclaredMethod(
        "onContainerAvailable",
        FragmentContainerView::class.java
    )
    method.isAccessible = true
    method.invoke(this, view)
}
```

This Screen is a part of Bottom navigation, when navigating to other screen `onPause()` is not called at all and coming back to the same screen here, it doesn't calls `onStart()` or `onResume()`. I guess this is why my map is not loaded.

I want to somehow trigger the lifecycle, also, If possible correct me if I'm going in some wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

when you navigate away and come back, the FragmentContainerView is still present in the view hierarchy, so it does not go through the lifecycle events onStart, onResume.

create a map view model

```
class MapViewModel : ViewModel() {
    
}
```

use the view mopdel to manage the map state

```
class MapFragment : Fragment() {
    private val mapViewModel: MapViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // Initialize and configure your map 
        // mapViewModel.initMap()
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
      
    }

}
```

use it in your composable

```
@Composable
fun MapScreen() {
    val mapViewModel: MapViewModel = viewModel()

    // val map = mapViewModel.getMap()

    // Render your map in the Composable
}
```